Can I create my own "New Project" template in Android Studio?
Now that I'm getting more experienced with Android Studio, I find that I prefer somewhat different project source skeletons than the ones provided for new projects by default (for example "New Activity" provides a MainActivity.kt that does too much - I want to push some of that down into my screens, and it would be nice to prepopulate some of the Room infrastructure Daos, Entities, etc). It's getting tiresome to have to keep readjusting the skeletons provided to get the boilerplate I want to start with.
Is there a way I can create my own template to choose from for new projects? I'm hoping I can customize one of the provided ones to my liking, then save it for future use.
I'm using Koala 2024.1.1 Patch 2

I looked into this yesterday as well. Like most things Android Studio it is impossibly hard to do what we want to do and the time taken makes it unviable.
I have, using help from both You Tube on (1)Room design and (2)kapt to ksp and (3)update to kotlin 2, finally managed to get an uptodate Room database which includes all the above functions and changes (only up to kotlin 2.0.0 (It does not work on kotlin v 2.0.20))
I then copied the project to a new folder called templates. I intend to keep that updated and any time I want to make a new database will use the template.
I know that this is not the answer that you hoped for but it is a relatively quick solution. If anyone else finds an exact solution I will be happy to use it.
Also using Koala Patch 2

Now successfully updated to kotlin version 2.0.20

When you say "use the template" I suspect you mean copy all the files manually from your 'template' folder into an existing newly-created project folder?
I suspect I'll be moving to this model as well - never using "New Project" but instead checking out a source skeleton from a local git repository I maintain, copying it over, and then using "Open Project". It's sad. It's making me long for emacs as a development environment, because at least I could extend it as I like.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I should add that I had to do a lot of work developing a script to massage my existing master repository into a fresh project ready for opening in AS/IntelliJ.
